# Import Blender files to SharpGL (openGL for c#)

Tags: opengl, c#, blender

please i have problem with import 3D models to SharpGL (openGL in c#).
Have you got pls any project where is this problem solved?
I need create any models in for example blender, and then import to sharpGL.
I try this 4 days, and without result. Please can you post me any project with loading (obj,3ds,...) files with texturing? I do big school project and without this i never completed this project.
Thank you for answer.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Well, what did you try and where have you failed? If you are familiar with 3D graphics at all, you can write a simple exporter in blender, or look up a loader for c# which can load fbx, obj or other popular file types.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at my own 3d .obj importer written in Java:

https://github.com/lukasz1985/Simple3dEngine/tree/shaders/src/io

look at classess: "ObjLoader" and "ObjParser" which is used by the former.

It should be pretty easy to adapt the code to C#.